# Typescript reduce an array of number literal type

Tags: typescript

Given

```
type DiceNumber = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6;
const rollDice = (): DiceNumber => (
    Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 1) + 1) as DiceNumber
)
```

When

```
const result = [...Array(4)].map(rollDice).reduce((acc, i) => acc + i)
```

Then Typescript is screaming `acc: DiceNumber Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'DiceNumber'.ts(2322) lib.es5.d.ts(1428, 24): The expected type comes from the return type of this signature`

`i: DiceNumber Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'DiceNumber'.ts(2322) lib.es5.d.ts(1428, 24): The expected type comes from the return type of this signature.`

The scream goes away if type is cast to number, e.g.

```
const diceNumber2Number = (diceNumber: DiceNumber): number => (diceNumber as number)
const result = [...Array(4)].map(rollDice).map(diceNumber2Number).reduce((acc, i) => acc + i)
```

Is there a better way to make the scream goes away without running the collection through a casting function? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript implicitly expects the first argument to `reduce` and the output type to be the same:

```
const result = [...Array(4)].map(rollDice).reduce((acc: DiceNumber, i: number): DiceNumber => acc + i)
```

But the output type of `acc + i` is not guaranteed to be `DiceNumber`. You can fix this by providing an explicit starting value:

```
const result = [...Array(4)].map(rollDice).reduce((acc, i) => acc + i, 0)
```

Since `0` is known to not be type `DiceNumber`, the `reduce` result is coerced to `number`. If for example you wanted to start at `1`, which is a `DiceNumber`, simply explicitly coerce `1 as number`.

```
const result = [...Array(4)].map(rollDice).reduce((acc, i) => acc + i, 1 as number)
```